# I can not understand the return value in this code

Tags: c++, return-value

what does `return { Memory::pHandle = pHandle };` in this code means ?
Is it the same as  `Memory::pHandle = pHandle`. if it is, then why return is used

```
HANDLE Memory::GetProcessHandle(DWORD ProcessID)
{
  HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);
  return { Memory::pHandle = pHandle };
}
```

Comment: The reason why `return` is used this way is because it saves precious keystrokes and electrons by not having to write `Memory::pHandle = pHandle; return pHandle;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value is the result of assigning the newly open process handle to the class member `pHandle`. I adjusted the code a bit to make it clearer for you.

```
HANDLE Memory::GetProcessHandle(DWORD ProcessID)
{
  HANDLE newpHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);
  Memory::pHandle = newpHandle;
  return Memory::pHandle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator=` returns the value that was assigned. So

```
return { Memory::pHandle = pHandle };
```

is the same as

```
Memory::pHandle = pHandle;
return pHandle;
```